# How get list of child groups in Ansible Jinja Template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I use ansible module template to create config.

I have a inventory file, that contains.

```
[workapp]
server1
[testapp]
server2
[db]
sdb
[app:children]
workapp
testapp
devapp
```

How i can get list child groups in app?
I tried do that in template file

```
{% for groups in groups['app'] %}
     {{ groups }}
{% endfor %}
```

But in this case i get list of servers in all child groups belong app, i.e

```
server1
server2
```

but i want get list

```
workapp
testapp
devapp
```

Any methods to get child groups?
Ansible version 2.9.27
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Unfortunately while running `ansible-playbook` itself, the short answer is: you can't. Ansible(-playbook) only has knowledge of the host to group relationship and not the parent/children one between groups. A possible workaround is to use `ansible-inventory` and a tool like `jq` but that probably won't solve your current issue. Example for your above scenario: `ansible-inventory -i your_inventory.ini --list | jq '.app.children'`

Comment: Thanks for asking, i use external script for generate my config. It's not beautiful, but working.